# I need to be able to close an internet tab, but i cannot close the browser

Tags: python

Im am writing a piece of code where it is vital that the browser stays open however i need to be able to close windows, to stop the browser from over populating. I have been using the webbrowser module but it seems that webbrowser doesnt have a way of close the tab once open. Any ideas?

**Remember the browser must stay open, so killing all tabs will close the browser. I must only close the tabs that were opened by my code!**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Sorry if this isn't in the right place, feel free to move it.

Software:
Python 3.6.4 (32 bit)

Modules used:
Time, Random and Webbrowser.

Comment: You could try using [selenium-python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Though there is no easy option to close a tab, you can [use keyboard shortcuts to achieve that behavior](https://gist.github.com/lrhache/7686903).

Answer (score 0):

Webbrowser is a limited api module for interfacing with popular browsers.

The way I see it you have a few options:

1. Find a module pertaining to the particular browser you're dealing with.
2. Work with the api of the browser(s) you're working with directly
3. Request feature of webbrowser in the future, but won't help you now, as they likely won't implement it any time soon.

Comment: I have reworked it to use the Selenium module, does the job a lot better than before.